# Filter diagrams with atlas coverage layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, rendering, atlas, atlas-generator

Please advise how I can hide diagrams outside of the coverage layer when using QGIS atlas function. I can do this for polygons,rasters etc without problem but whatever I do I cannot hide diagrams from other layers. Please see example below. Basically I do not want anything outside of the polygons..

[image]

Comment: You can use mask plugin.

Comment: plugin does not seem to work with QGIS 2.18 (no other options due to difficult administrators). This question not same as proposed duplicate because also covering diagrams which has  different settings. The answers to other question did not work when i tried

Comment: You can hide the labels with the mask, but I could not hide the diagrams. I do not think there is any solution at this time, sorry. I have some screenshots for hidding labels, but I cant upload it, the question is blocked.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I still cannot get any solution to work (including one marked as duplicate). I edited this question to make it diagram specific. If you can post a good answer either here or on the other question it would be most helpful. thx

Comment: Dissolve your poligons to one with specific field, and select that poligon, use mask plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution, using a condition on the size of the diagram: if the entity is out of the coverage, I put the diagram size to zero:

```
if( attribute($atlasfeature,  'atlas_field_name' ) = current_field_name  , siez_field_name , 0)
```